# Cisco process memory usage

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, snmp

I am trying to monitor a Cisco process memory usage. This is what I get with the command line:

```
show system internal processes memory | inc PID|ipfib
 PID TTY      STAT     TIME MAJFLT  TRS   RSS    VSZ %MEM COMMAND
 6069 ?        Ssl  00:14:01      0    0 169480 532812  1.0 /lc/isan/bin/ipfib
```

I want to use my SNMP poller to get this information, so far I have only found 
1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.109.1.2.1.1 has all the process names, pid, process usage.

All I need is the memory usage, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a device with an ipfib process available, but assuming you're running IOS, the principles are the same no matter what the process name is...

### Find the index for the process in question:

First, walk [cpmProcessName](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.109.1.2.1.1.2) and find the index... for instance, I'll look for "ARP Input"...

```
(py27_test)[mpenning@tsunami fast]$ snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c public 10.1.1.1  \
  .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.109.1.2.1.1.2 | grep "ARP Input"
CISCO-PROCESS-MIB::cpmProcessName.1.12 = STRING: ARP Input
CISCO-PROCESS-MIB::cpmProcessName.1.239 = STRING: RARP Input
(py27_test)[mpenning@tsunami fast]$
```

We can see the index for the "ARP Input" process is 1.12...

### All memory allocated:

Now let's find all the memory that was ever allocated to this process.  We will do an `snmpget` on [cpmProcExtMemAllocatedRev](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=cpmProcExtMemAllocatedRev&translate=Translate&submitValue=SUBMIT&submitClicked=true)... be sure to append 1.12 to the cpmProcExtMemAllocatedRev OID...

```
(py27_test)[mpenning@tsunami fast]$ snmpget -v 2c -c public 10.1.1.1 \
  .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.109.1.2.3.1.1.1.12
CISCO-PROCESS-MIB::cpmProcExtMemAllocatedRev.1.12 = Gauge32: 1259940452 bytes
(py27_test)[mpenning@tsunami fast]$
```

[cpmProcExtMemAllocatedRev](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=cpmProcExtMemAllocatedRev&translate=Translate&submitValue=SUBMIT&submitClicked=true) is the sum of *all memory ever allocated* to the process; that means you'll have to subtract all memory that was ever freed from the process.

### All memory freed:

To find all the memory that was ever freed, poll the [cpmProcExtMemFreedRev](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=cpmProcExtMemFreedRev&translate=Translate&submitValue=SUBMIT&submitClicked=true) OID, and append the index (1.12)...

```
(py27_test)[mpenning@tsunami fast]$ snmpget -v 2c -c public 10.1.1.1 \
  .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.109.1.2.3.1.2.1.12
CISCO-PROCESS-MIB::cpmProcExtMemFreedRev.1.12 = Gauge32: 1259931892 bytes
(py27_test)[mpenning@tsunami fast]$
```

### Totals / math:

So the total memory used by my "ARP Input" process is:

```
AllocatedMem - FreedMem   = MemoryUsed

1259940452   - 1259931892 = *8560 Bytes*
```